# Flutter Android Build Gradle error configuring root project 'android'?

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, build.gradle

I'm getting the following error trying to run my android project from Flutter...

> `A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for root project 'android' of
>   type org.gradle.api.Project.`

Here is my android/build.gradle file...

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.51'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.10.2, 0.99.99]'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
//subprojects {
//    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
//}

subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "27.0.1"
            }
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> `A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for root project 'android' of
> type org.gradle.api.Project.`

The error was [due to where you applied the `onesignal-gradle-plugin`](https://github.com/OneSignal/react-native-onesignal/issues/550#issuecomment-396015932). The line `apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'` should be applied in your `app/build.gradle` not in the root `build.gradle` or `android/build.gradle`.